# How to read non-delimited JSON using Pig?

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a json file where raw text looks like this:

```
{a:1,b:2,c:3}{a:3,b:3,c:5}{a:3,b:3,c:9}
```

Doing

```
raw = LOAD 'jsonfile.text' USING JsonLoader('a:chararry,b:chararray,c:chararry') ;

dump raw;
```

only returns 1 record.

Actual excerpt from log:

> Input(s): Successfully read 1 records (630644858 bytes) from:
>   "s3n://logstash/ls.s3.ip-10-45-56-56.2016-03-02T23.10.part42.txt"
>
> Output(s): Successfully stored 1 records (1900 bytes) in:
>   "hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/temp-1489272670/tmp-1959659634"

It looks like only the first record of the JSON is being read. The Json file is not delimited.

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Add an envelope for the malformed json?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing a first pass which does the string replacement `}{` -> `}\n{`. Then you will have one valid json object per line, and the json parsing should work.

Comment: a = LOAD 's3n://logstash/ls.s3.ip-10-45-56-56.2016-03-02T23.13.part55.txt' as (raw:chararray);

b = foreach a generate REPLACE(raw, '}', '}\n');


is there anyway I can load the alias using Jsonloader without having to save it down first?

Answer (score 0):

Check the twitter elephant bird jar, that can be used to work with literally any kind of JSON data.

Check this for reference - Sample pig script working on JSON Data similar to yours!

**https://gist.github.com/neilkod/2898455**

Hope this helps!! <><

Comment: Thanks for the link. I use the elephant bird jar too, unfortunately didn't work. I ended just replacing "}" with "}\\n". Was hoping there would be another solution.